# Selenium webdriver iterate and navigate over multiple links in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

Migrating away from Casper.js to Selenium to have more tools.

Attempting to iterate through multiple links and navigate them using node.js and selenium-webdriver.

Can't find any documentation or examples and I keep getting an error no matter which loop I try to run.

```
iLinkCount = oLinks.length;
    console.log( oLinks );
    console.log( iLinkCount );
```

> Code above outputs the link count to the console but I am unable to get their href tags to continue on with my testing.

```
driver.findElements(webdriver.By.css( 'snip' ) ).then(function( oLinks ) {
// driver.findElements(webdriver.By.xpath( "//snip" ) ).then(function( oLinks ) {
    iLinkCount = oLinks.length;
    console.log( oLinks );
    console.log( iLinkCount );

    // for( var oLink in oLinks ){
    //     var sLink = oLink.getAttribute('href');
    //     console.log( sLink );
    // }


    for( var i = 0; i < iLinkCount; i++ ){
        var oLink = oLinks.get( i );
        console.log( oLink );
        // var sLink = oLinks[ i ].getAttribute('href');
        // console.log( sLink );
    }
});
```

Every loop I attempt to use to iterate over the links I get an error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

What's wrong with my loops?

Any good references on examples/REAL USAGE documentation on driving selenium-webdriver with node?

After searching far and wide all that appears to be semi-documented are java/python samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that [this documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebElement.html) is quite good.

The problem with your code is, when you look at the documentation, `findElements` returns an array of `WebElement`, and that has no `get` method, one thing I have learnt is, if you are going to play with `selenium` in javascript, you need to understands the concept of `Promise` properly( and make sure do not do any anti-promise pattern), simply put, most of the cases you talk to the driver( call some method in it), you get a promise in return that has the value you desire and not the actual value itself.

The function for retriving href based on css selector:

```
function getAllHrefs(driver, cssValue){
    var selector;
    if(!cssValue)   selector = By.tagName('a');
    else            selector = By.css(cssValue);
    return driver.findElements(selector).then(function(oLinks){
        var allPromises = oLinks.map(function(oLink){
            return oLink.getAttribute('href');
        });
        return Driver.promise.all(allPromises);
    });     
}
```

Example for the above function:

```
var dummyPage = 'http://google.com'
 , Driver = require('selenium-webdriver')
 , By = require('selenium-webdriver').By
 , chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
 , driver
;


driver = getDriverInstance();
driver.get(dummyPage);
getAllHrefs(driver).then(function(hrefs){
    console.log('got hrefs: ', hrefs.length, hrefs);
});


function getAllHrefs(driver, cssValue){
    var selector;
    if(!cssValue)   selector = By.tagName('a');
    else            selector = By.css(cssValue);
    return driver.findElements(selector).then(function(oLinks){
        var allPromises = oLinks.map(function(oLink){
            return oLink.getAttribute('href');
        });
        return Driver.promise.all(allPromises);
    });     
}

function getDriverInstance(){  
    var driverInstance = new Driver.Builder()
        .usingServer()
        .withCapabilities({
            browserName: 'chrome'
        })
        .setChromeOptions(
            new chrome.Options()
                .addArguments('--privileged')
                .addArguments('--no-sandbox')
        )
        .build();
    return driverInstance;
}
```